# Node-tap Protocol updating a spec.ts.cjs snapshot

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, snapshot-testing

Using the example from [node-tap-snapshot-examples](https://node-tap.org/plugins/snapshot/), I created a snapshot using the command `tap tagger.test.mjs --snapshot` for the following test (Modified TS version).

```
// tagger.spec.ts
import t from 'tap'
import tagger from './tagger.spec.ts'
t.matchSnapshot(tagger('tagName', 'content'), 'output')
```

A snapshot CJS file is being created. Now when I update a test with another test, I will require an updated snapshot. I looked into the documentation and couldnt see a snapshot command for updating a snapshot. So I tried the same command after updating my test file with new tests. and as a result all I see is an error,

`x must match snapshot`

My question is how can I create or update a new snapshot? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a very easy solution.

`npm run tap -- --snapshot filename.spec.ts`